# Homebrew Python and writing to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/?

Tags: python, homebrew

Is there a definitive guide for how to install Homebrew's Python properly, along with pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper etc.?

I've read the following pages:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python
http://osxastrotricks.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/python-setup-with-homebrew/
http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/11/13/installing-django-in-virtual-environment-on-mac/
http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/
http://youshoulddoityourself.blogspot.com.au/2010/11/test.html

I have OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion) DP3, and I installed the XCode Command Line Tools.

I also installed XQuartz as well, just in case (10.8 doesn't provide it).

I then ran:

```
brew install python  --universal --framework
```

I added the following to my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/python:${PATH}"
```

I then ran:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

which seemed to work.

I check where pip's installed:

```
 Victors-MacBook-Pro:~ victorhooi$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

However, when I try to pip install packages, I get an error complaining about not being able to write to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:

```
running install_lib

creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/yolk

error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/yolk': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import  setuptools;__file__='/Users/victorhooi/build/yolk/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/gg/m37t1rkx4zj7z54ls487jfc40000gn/T/pip-ap7LSB-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /Users/victorhooi/build/yolk
Storing complete log in /Users/victorhooi/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

My understanding was that Homebrew's Python would install into it's own site-packages, and I wouldn't need to do weird chown's all over the filesystem tree to get things to work?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: I'm having the same issue after a fresh install of mountain lion. I did have a similar question(http://stackoverflow.com/q/11423301/153865). Which I answered myself. There is a section in my question for altering the symlinks in /System to point to the brew directories, but that seems like a hack. Hopefully someone will answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, as someone who has been exactly where you are, start using virtual environments first, then pip and the rest. They are awesome, and will solve this and many future problems.

Comment: Huh, wait, I am using virtualenvs *confused*. I though I mentioned them in the first line? My normal setup is to use easy_install to install pip, then use pip to install virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper - I usually also throw in yolk, so I can see what's installed.

Comment: Try easy_install > virtualenv > pip > yolk. Activate a venv after installing it.

Answer (score 10):

Meanwhile, homebrew's python has evolved:

- Python installed via brew no longer tries to write to `/Library/Python`.
- Homebrew's Python now always uses its own site-packages.
- pip (and distribute) is installed automatically.
- The "--framework" option is not needed. Homebrew defaults to it now.
- XQuartz is needed (unfortunately) because the Tk headers link to X11 headers.

Your PATH in the .bashrc is correct (and still needed).

Comment: Let's pretend I don't care about Tk.  Is there a way to not install X11 in that case?

Comment: Soon there will. See [that issue](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/14989).

Comment: That issue that I filed?  Yeah, I've been following it.  :)  (And thank you for your work on it, by the way!)

Comment: "Homebrew's Python now always uses its own site-packages." — That's what I expected, [but it's not what I'm seeing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27952596/656912).

Answer (score -1):

Now that there is Mountain Lion 10.8.2 out and I had a legacy Python 2.7 install from Lion things just didn't work. Whatever I tried, Python wanted to access /Library/.. No good. The easy solution is to `brew uninstall python` and then `brew install python` That solves pretty much all Python related problems with homebrew on ML.