# Correctly Installing and configuring Python/Pyside/PyDev on OS X Lion (and likely future versions of OS X)

Tags: python, eclipse, osx-lion, pyside

I am having issues with PyDev not auto completing pyside correctly, I suspect that I am missing a crucial step in the installation process.

So, How does one install and configure a fresh OS X lion install to develop pyside ?

**Note:** This Question does NOT belong on another stack site. This is what a programmer has to do to get his machine in shape to develop python PySide using PyDev. A system administrator is unlikely to have encountered this specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you followed the various scattered documentation around and mixed different python interpreters and python tools. Also Step 4 below needs to also be done, which not many guides mention.

To get the system in a state for PySide development in line with a linux distro, where all the plumbing aligns by default you have to do the following steps:

Step 1 : install Xcode, brew, and xcode command line tools (you will find documentation for this on the brew website). Once you have Xcode and command line tools downloaded and installed the following command line should install brew.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

Check everything is OK with `brew doctor`.

add the path for user installed binaries to `~/.profile` or `/etc/paths` with a text editor (`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`). Make sure the new path is before the `$PATH` (or at the top of `/etc/paths` and not after).

Also, after install you want to make sure any python admin utilities that you use are picked up from the correct directory. For this add `/usr/local/share/python` to the path next to the new path you specified above. This is important because you want easy_install to be correctly functioning and installing to your version of python and not sox's, below we verify that the correct items are being picked up.

Step 2: Use brew to install python2.7.*

```
brew install readline sqlite gdbm pkg-config
brew install python --framework --universal
```

Step 3: verify the python binary and the easy_install binary are in the correct directories. You do this by using [`which` and not `whereis`](https://superuser.com/questions/430002/whereis-and-which-return-different-paths-in-mac-os-x).

Step 4: Since OSX has the funky notion of frameworks, for library management, we have to symlink things so that other tools (such as eclipse) can auto config correctly.

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
sudo rm Current
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
# following might not be needed or advised (see discussion below).
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
sudo rm Current
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
```

Step 5: Install pyside using brew (`brew install pydev`). This also installs Qt4 as a dependency.

Step 6: [Install Eclipse along with PyDev](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html)

Step 7: Configure eclipse. Do not auto configure, manually add a new interpreter and supply `/usr/local/bin/python` as the python path. It should pick up the libraries automatically. Also add `PySide` to the built-ins, since PySide autocompletion requires active introspection, rather than static code analysis.

Step 8: install pip `easy_install install pip`

Provided you use `pip` or `brew` for getting further python code, you should get things piping into the correct directories. That is till mountain lion comes along and ruins your day :D

**note to self**

I Know now that dependency management is no easier in python compared to windows .net or C/C++ (CRT) GAC or Linux's soname's or java's class path. We all end of with a maze of indirections.

Comment: Do you actually need to brew install python instead of using the built-in Lion Python 2.7? PySide's own packages are made to work with built-in Python, and that's the way it builds by default if you build from source. And there's no problem with easy_install/pip. So what exactly forces the use of a second Python? Also, why do you have to hack up /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework? What happens when an OS update comes along and breaks that? (It's possible that all of this actually is necessary to work around some bug, but some reference to that bug would be nice.)

Comment: Well all the reading I have done says install a up to date python over OS X's supplied one. PyDev says it, Python.org says it, brew says it :D. When a new OS version comes around, the process has to be run again from scratch. I was using osx's python before I rebuilt everything, I couldn't get PyDev configured no matter what I tried. someone more savvy with python / os x / eclipse would probably be able to fix the problem =D. I just though tracking brew's recipes would be better than learning everything in detail.

Comment: Also when one adds complex python libraries (--i.e., ones with dynamic C/C++ libraries) using brew, I think the most painless method is to have a brew python installed.

Comment: That being said, brew does include a python package that isn't in homebrew-dupes. But it also has https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Gems%2C-Eggs-and-Perl-Modules which is basically about how you can install eggs that the system Python will use. Also, most python libraries with dylibs, I install with easy_install or pip (after installing their prereqs with brew, of course) whenever possible, as that seems more in keeping with the brew way of doing things. Finally, just upgrading from 10.7.4 to 10.7.5 means I have to reinstall everything your way? That's a good reason not to do it that way…

Comment: Homebrew doesn't install certain dupes, and for the nonsense dupes it complains. It doesn't complain with python. If you look at some of the recipe's some even state they prefer the homebrew version of python. On the python os x page I find this quote "Python comes pre-installed on Mac OS X, but due to Apple's release cycle, it's often one or even two years old. The overwhelming recommendation of the "MacPython" community is to upgrade your Python by downloading and installing a newer version from "

Comment: I can't be sure, but I doubt apple trashes the unix subsystem for anything but major version changes. There'd be a lot of pissed off scientists in this world if that was the case, since the majority use the unix subsystem and compile there own stuff :D

Comment: That's my point: They don't trash the Unix subsystem, but they _do_ trash the /System directory; that's the whole reason they have one, because (unlike /Library) they can rely on the fact that no end user or third-party software will ever tamper with it.

Comment: well System wasn't directly mentioned in any of the information I went over. However, some people created that symlink there as well, so I included it for completeness. If I understand things correctly, OS X's supplied interpreter, when used with python cocoa stuff should still be able to find the libraries they need even though the `current` symnlink pointing elsewhere. Am I right ? Updating my post above.